# Как получить ссылку на конкретную песню в вк?

Tags: вконтакте, музыка

Я посмотрела видео, и попробовала также получить ссылку на музыку вк, но что-то пошло не так
[image: В вк кликаю лкм по песне, в выпадающем меню выбираю проверка кода][image: Дальше выбираю раздел сеть и отключаю кэш]

[image: Копирую ссылку]

[image: И эта ссылка выводит не то, что мне нужно]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В вк я кликнула лкм по песне и в выпадающем меню выбрала проверить код. Дальше выбрала Сеть и отключить кэш. (Это по видео, еще надо было нажать на Media, но я его не нашла). Скопировала ссылку, а она показывает не то, что нужно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Получилось. Установила расширение браузера для скачивания файлов(SaveFrom.net), пликнула лкм по песне, нажала скопировать сслылку. И она работает)